# Connecting .net 6 application with Identity Server 3

Tags: .net-6.0, identityserver3

We have Identity Server 3 configured for our organization.

I am creating an application in .Net6 and want to connect and show the login page from Identity Server 3. But it seems like there are fair bit of challenges in it.

I am using the following code in .net6 application in Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("cookie", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "mvcclient";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "MyAuthorityUrlGoesHere";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.ClientId = "MyClientIdGoesHere";
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.ResponseType = "id_token"; //for implicit flow
});
```

The page redirects to the identity server but displays the
error - "The client application is not known or is not authorized."

I think it is due to the fact that we need to set "RedirectUri" too in implicit flow, but somehow there is no property named RedirectUri any more :(

I couldnt find any links on google where they talk about connecting .net 6 application to identity server3. Although I was able to connect a .net4.5 application to identity server 3 and it shows a login page and then redirect me back to .net application.

Can someone please guide me through connecting .net 6 application to identity server 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer myself in another stack overflow thread:

In asp core there is a subpath silently appended

soo http://localhost:49946/signin-oidc had to be added to the redirect uris on identity server. And we dont need to give redirecturl at client

Comment: Hi, will you please link the StackOverflow thread where you found the answer. It will be helpful if you update your answer with code snippets.